# sql to linq and 2 query into 1

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Good day.
I have 2 requests.

```
SELECT cf.Conf_StartTime, cf.Conf_DisplayName, eve.Conf_ID, eve.Party_ID, eve.Point_NAME, eve.Ongoing_ID, COUNT(*) AS 'num'
FROM CDR_EVENT as eve INNER JOIN CDR_Conference as cf ON eve.Conf_ID = cf.Conf_ID 
WHERE TIMESTAMP >= '9/10/2020' AND TIMESTAMP <= '9/11/2020' AND Ongoing_ID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
cf.Conf_StartTime, cf.Conf_DisplayName, eve.Conf_ID, eve.Party_ID, eve.Point_NAME, eve.Ongoing_ID
HAVING COUNT (*) >= 2
ORDER BY eve.Conf_ID

GO

SELECT cf.Conf_StartTime, cf.Conf_DisplayName, eve.Conf_ID, eve.Party_ID, eve.Point_NAME, eve.Disconnect_Cause_DESCRIPTION, COUNT(*) AS 'num'
FROM CDR_EVENT as eve INNER JOIN CDR_Conference as cf ON eve.Conf_ID = cf.Conf_ID 
WHERE TIMESTAMP >= '9/10/2020' AND TIMESTAMP <= '9/11/2020' AND Disconnect_Cause_DESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL AND Disconnect_Cause_ID != '2'
GROUP BY
cf.Conf_StartTime, cf.Conf_DisplayName, eve.Conf_ID, eve.Party_ID, eve.Point_NAME, Disconnect_Cause_DESCRIPTION
HAVING COUNT (*) >= 1
ORDER BY cf.Conf_DisplayName
```

Question 1. How to convert them to LINQ?

Question 2. Is it possible to combine these two queries into one?

Comment: Need to see the client side entity definitions and mappings

Comment: What exactly to see on the client side?
To simplify the request, then:
I'm trying to figure out how to translate the request structure itself into a linq format


``SELECT db1.NAME1, db1.NAME2, db2.NAME3, db2.NAME4, db2.NAME5, db2.NAME6, COUNT(*) AS 'num'
FROM CDR_db2NT as db2 INNER JOIN CDR_Conference as db1 ON db2.NAME3 = db1.NAME3 
WHERE NAME6 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
db1.NAME1, db1.NAME2, db2.NAME3, db2.NAME4, db2.NAME5, db2.NAME6
HAVING COUNT (*) >= 2
ORDER BY db2.NAME3``

Comment: We can't give you any C# without knowing the names of the types, properties and collections on the C# side. You also didn't state whether you wanted method or query syntax.. And it'd help to have a stab at it first, otherwise you're effectively just asking us to do your work for you (commonplace in SQL tag but less so in C#)

Comment: I may not quite understand.
I use LINQ queries in the program.
In this case, I was able to make SQL requests, and I want to apply it in the program as LINQ requests.
Essentially no name details are required. If I understand correctly, I need the syntax of the request itself so that I can already adjust it to the values

Comment: Please show an example of an existing LINQ query that works; I want to see what it works "on"

Comment: `var obj = from t in dataContext.CDR_Conference
where (t.Conf_DisplayName.StartsWith("80") && !t.Conf_Name.Contains("dmadirectlync") && 
t.Conf_DisplayName.Contains("(") && 
t.Conf_DisplayName.Contains(")") && 
t.Conf_StartTime.Date >= dTimeStart.Date && 
t.Conf_StartTime.Date <= dTimeEnd.Date && 
t.Conf_Duration >= 600)
select new
{
s1 = t.Conf_Name.Trim(),
s2 = t.Conf_DisplayName.Trim(),
etc...
};`

Comment: I think I was able to convert to LINQ, it turned out to be not difficult. 
**Question** # 2 is still valid :)
`var obj = from cdr in dataContext.CDR_EVENT
c.Conf_ID
where (cdr.TIMESTAMP.Date >= dTimeStart.Date && cdr.TIMESTAMP.Date <= dTimeEnd.Date && cdr.Ongoing_ID != null)
group (cdr) by new {cdr.Conf_ID, cdr.Party_ID,cdr.Ongoing_ID, cdr.Point_NAME } into g
orderby g.Key.Party_ID
select new
{
s1 = g.Key.Conf_ID,
s2 = g.Key.Party_ID,
s5 = g.Count()
};`

Comment: *Is it possible to combine* is really hard to answer without seeing sample data; yes, in theory, it is

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to convert to LINQ, it turned out to be not difficult.
Question # 2 is still valid :)

```
var obj = from cdr in dataContext.CDR_EVENT
where (cdr.TIMESTAMP.Date >= dTimeStart.Date && cdr.TIMESTAMP.Date <= dTimeEnd.Date && 
cdr.Ongoing_ID != null)
group (cdr) by new {cdr.Conf_ID, cdr.Party_ID,cdr.Ongoing_ID, cdr.Point_NAME } into g
where g.Count() >=2
orderby g.Key.Party_ID
select new
{
   s1 = g.Key.Conf_ID,
   s2 = g.Key.Party_ID,
   s3 = g.Key.Ongoing_ID,
   s4 = g.Key.Point_NAME,
   s5 = g.Count()
};
```